# Inserting String with slash into Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Actually I am just trying to insert string something like this ***30/01/2012*** into a table where that particular table column is of type varchar. After insertion this value is changed into *0.008946322067594433*. What may be the reason for this behaviour? Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. I am very poor in database/SQL concepts.

Comment: A varchar column should not see any change in the data. Show some code.

Comment: I suspect that change is happening **before** the insert... are you enclosing that in "'s? Please show us the code.

Comment: show us your code dude..

Comment: I agree with Jon Skeet answer. But consider a bad practice to use varchar in a DB to hold Date as most of the database have a specific Date type. All date manipulation / business rules can be done in java side afterwards.

Comment: Guys I made the mistake what Jon Skeet what was pointing out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your SQL looks something like:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (X) VALUES (30/01/2012)
```

in which case it's not treating it as a *string*, but an expression to evaluate - which is then being converted into a string. If this is the case, it sounds like you're building up your SQL string *including the value*, e.g.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO ... VALUES (" + value + ")";
```

**Don't do that.** Use a `PreparedStatement` and set parameter values instead. Not only will it avoid this problem, it will also avoid SQL injection attacks, conversion problems with dates and times, etc.

(Speaking of which, assuming this value is meant to be a date, why are you storing it in a varchar column? If you possibly can, make your columns represent the data you wish to store more naturally...)

EDIT: I've just downloaded and installed MySQL to test this... and indeed in a table with a single column (`Name`) this SQL statement does the wrong thing (in MySQL Workbench):

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`sandbox` (`Name`) VALUES (30/01/2012);
```

... but this does the right thing:

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`sandbox` (`Name`) VALUES ('30/01/2012');
```

But you should still use a prepared statement with parameters, of course.

Comment: Thanks. I will use prepared statement here onwards.